# Facebook, Attachment Unavailable error when using the send button?

Tags: php, facebook, send

I am using the send button to share a link and a message on a app but I get this error when I try to read the message:

```
Attachment Unavailable
The privacy settings on this attachment do not allow you to view it.
```

I get the message but can't see the attachment. The attachment should be a link!

Here is the code I use:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d){
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
    </script>
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://apps.facebook.com/app_profile?id=<?php echo $id;?>" data-font="arial" ></div>
```

any ideas?

edit:

I've read more about this `Send` button and I set up all `Open Graph` and added `Privacy Policy URL` inside my app. The `Like` and `Share` buttons work just fine

I've also added the `ref` tag and basically tried everything.

Is this a facebook bug?

edit2:

my fbml code as well:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
s = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<fb:send ref="some_ref>" href="http://apps.facebook.com/profile?id=<?php echo $user_profile['id'];?>&amp;ref=some_ref" font="arial">Send private message</fb:send>
```

Comment: When and how are you trying to read the attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this code simply from [Send Button - Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) but edited little bit to fit your case

This part should be in "body" tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

"ref" value can contain alphanumeric characters and some punctuation (currently +/=-.:_)

```
<fb:send ref="some_ref" 
        href="http://apps.facebook.com/profile?id=<?=$user_profile['id'];?>" 
        font="arial">Send private message</fb:send>
```

Before you use FBML, make sure you are adding this xml namespace to "html" tag

```
<html xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

if you use XHTML as DOCTYPE you may use

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: it seems that your code or my code works only for 50% of the time. I start to believe that facebook has some fault into this. Thanks for your time, ill mark it as complete, though if someone else reads this post ill let them know that my script start working also

Comment: facebook development process is not clear to do because they depracated some APIs and did not update their documentation well... I agree to your point

Answer (score 1):

Check that You not have double `FB.init`. I got the same error and I found that I had put `FB.init` to top of the page and to the footer too.

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 error in your code ref="some_ref>" should be ref="some_ref"

also, Please check that the href parameter is accessible from the fb server ..